# wp_remote_get( $url, $args ) not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to request data from the virgin giving api to display my fundraising information on my blog. I'm a complete novice and have been unable to workout how such a task would be completed after reading and trying out everything I can find on the topic. This is the code I have been using in a .php file within a wordpress installation on cloud9 (I have removed the search and api key). I have also tried the code on a page on my live blog which is hosted with Bluehost. I'm not sure if I'm creating the page in the correct location or if the below code should be wrapped in some sort of function. Any help that you can provide would be much appreciated.

```
$url = "https://api.virginmoneygiving.com/fundraisers/v1/";

$args = array(
'headers' => array( "Content-type" => "application/json" ), 
'httpversion' => 1.1,
);

$response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

$response_code =  wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );

print_r( $response_code  );

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 2):

`'httpversion'` takes a string...

```
'httpversion' => '1.1',
```

Read more [in the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-http.php#L49).

Comment: Thanks for that, I altered the code but still nothing - I can't get anything to show on the page.

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($response)`? I'm suspicious that it actually *is* connecting, but that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Melvis, thanks for helping out, just tried var_dump(response) and still nothing.

Comment: I get nothing, the page refreshes and remains completely blank.

Comment: Where are you putting that code? Also, do you have debugging on? "Completely blank" implies a PHP error (such as a syntax error)

Comment: Just inspected source in chrome and the following error shows: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). I have the same error on both cloud 9 and my blog address: cyclehacker.com/virgin_api_test.php

Comment: So the error is on your server, and doesn't have anything to do with the `wp_remote_get()` connection. I'd enable PHP/WordPress debugging and try to get an error printout to see what the issue is.

Comment: I'm just putting the code into a blank php file which sits in the same location as the wp-config.php file

Comment: Not sure how to turn on debugging

Comment: There's good info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), but you should only have to add the following line to *wp-config.php*: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: OK turned debugging on and the error is no longer visible in inspect element. There is basically no code showing when I view source?? Where would I find debugging errors?

Comment: Is `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);` set?

Comment: Just added it to both. Something seems to be stopping the code from displaying.